# Asymptotic formula for $\sum_{k=N}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ as $N \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, euler-maclaurin

This seems like a weird question, because the series has good convergence and there's no need to use other methods to estimate it for $N \to \infty$.

However, after seeing [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1767408/269624), I tried to come up with some approximation which could allow us to treat integrals containing this sum in the denominator.

Regardless of the particular application, I just wanted to ask if there's a way to approximate this sum using a finite combination of elementary or special functions?

Not counting the obvious $e^x-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}$ of course.

Euler-Maclaurin formula doesn't seem very promising, because the resulting integral is even more complicated $$\int_N^\infty \frac{x^y}{\Gamma(y+1)}dy$$ And the derivatives containing various combinations of polygamma functions are also a pain to write.

If there's no better asymptotic expression than the sum itself, so be it.

Comment: How about trying asymptotic methods for the integral form of the remainder for the Maclaurin expansion of $\mathrm{e}^x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{n!}{x^n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}
=1+\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^{k-n}n!}{k!}\\
$$
and for $n\ge|x|$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^{k-n}n!}{k!}\right|
&\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{|x|^k}{(n+1)^k}\\
&=\frac{|x|}{n+1-|x|}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}
=\frac{x^n}{n!}\left(1+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\right)
$$

Answer (score 3):

In another way, note that your sum is related with the [Regularized Incomplete Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables).
$$
\eqalign{
  & Q(s,z) = {{\Gamma (s,z)} \over {\Gamma (s)}} = e^{-z} \sum_{k = 0}^{s} {{{z^{k}} \over {k!}}}
  = \left( {1 - e^{-z} \sum_{k=s}^{\infty } {{{z^k} \over {k!}}} } \right)\quad  \Longrightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Longrightarrow \quad \sum _{k=s}^{\infty } {{{z^{k}} \over {k!}}}  = e^{z} P(s,z) = e^{z} {{\gamma (s,z)} \over {\Gamma (s)}} \cr} 
$$
note that here the summation is taken in the [Antidelta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum) meaning.

Therefore, using the asymptotic expansion of $Q(s,z)$ for $s \, \to \, \infty$ we get
$$
\sum_{k=s}^{\infty } {{{z^k} \over {k!}}}  = \sum_{k = s}^{\infty } {{{z^k} \over {k!}}}
  = e^{z} P(s,z) = {{s^{- s - 1/2} e^{s} z^{s} } \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}\left( {1 + {{12z - 1} \over {12s}}
 + O\!\left( {{1 \over {s^{\,2} }}} \right)} \right),\quad  \left| s \right| \to \infty.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Maple tells me it's
$$\dfrac{x^n}{n!} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n} + \frac{x(x-1)}{n^2} + \frac{x(x^2-3x+1)}{n^3} + \frac{x(x^3 - 6x^2 + 7x - 1)}{n^4} + O(1/n^5)\right)$$

You can get this by a similar method to robjohn's.

Comment: Thank you for providing more terms