# Approximating finite sum of factorial reciprocal

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'd like to approximate
$$\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k!}$$

I know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}=e$ but since I am dealing with only the finite case I'm not sure this approximation is very good. Is there a better one? Note: Not looking for the closed form with the $\Gamma$ function, an approximation in terms of elementary functions is desired.

Comment: Hint: what terms in the sum for $e$ are missing?

Comment: $$0<e-\sum_1^N\frac1{k!}<\frac{N+2}{(N+1)\cdot (N+1)!}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That is correct only if you start summing from $k=0$.

Comment: No sure what you call a very good approximation. There is no problem tabulating the, say, first $20$ values. Then any term that you add will make no difference to a double-precision float.

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {\frac{1}{{k!}}}  \sim e - 1 - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\frac{{e^N }}{{N^{N + 3/2} }}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{12N}} - \frac{{287}}{{288N^2 }} +  \cdots } \right)
$$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3279850

Comment: @Gary whoops. Yes, replace $e$ with $e-1$ in my inequality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an exact representation
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!}=e\frac{ \Gamma (n+1,1)}{\Gamma (n+1)}-1=\frac{\lfloor e \,n!\rfloor }{n!}-1$$

Comment: +1 Very nice! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Taylor's formula, you get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k!} = e - 1 -\frac{e^{\xi}}{(N+1)!}, \quad \xi \in (0,1)
$$

So, if you choose to approximate the sum by $e-1$, the error you commit is bounded by $\frac{e}{(N+1)!}$. As an example, if $N=10$ you get an error of the order $10^{-8}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it possible you could elaborate on how $\frac{e^{\xi}}{(N+1)!}$ is derived from the taylor formula?

Comment: If $f\in c^{N+1}$ in some open set centred in $a$ and containing $x$, we have that
$$
f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \cdots + \frac{f^{(N)}(a)}{N!}(x-a)^N + \frac{f^{(N+1)}(\xi)}{(N+1)!}(x-a)^{N+1}, \quad \xi \in (a,x).
$$
In this case, since $a=0$, $x=1$ and $f^{(N+1)}(x) = e^x$, we have that
$$
\left| \dfrac{f^{(N+1)}(\xi)}{(N+1)!}(1-0)^{N+1}\right| = \dfrac{e^{\xi}}{(N+1)!}\leq \frac{e}{(N+1)!}
$$

Comment: @a6623 Please consider marking as correct the answer by Claude Leibovici. Note that the formula he presented, although derived using the $\Gamma$ function, does not actually use it in the calculations. For instance,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{10}\frac{1}{k!} = \frac{\lfloor e 10!\rfloor}{10!} -1 = \frac{6235301}{3628800}
$$

This is an exact result. It can't get any better!